# android:AlarmManager doesn't fire alarm events

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'd like my app performs some work periodically.To do it I'm using `AlarmManager` but for some reason it doesn't fire any events.
Manifest xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="test.user.alarm_test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity code:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    findViewById(R.id.startAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            start();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cancel();
        }
    });
}

public void start() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval = 5000;
     //schedule alarm to fire every 5 seconds
    manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval, interval, pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void cancel() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Alarm receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

UPD:I found `manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval, interval, pendingIntent);`(RTC instead of ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP) works better but now it calls onReceive only one time.

Comment: your receiver in manifest is missing action field

Comment: what action do I need to add to receiver?I don't see any hints in the google's doc https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 0):

My fault android won't let creating alarm events less often than one per 60 seconds.So I just needed to wait some time.